# android/log.h not found when building with cmake

Tags: android-ndk, cmake

I've started developing with Android NDK in Android Studio but it's a big pain since it doesn't have a proper C++ support. So I try to create a cmake project to build my stuff. I've used [android-cmake](https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake) and it works well so far, except for the fact that `<android/log.h>`, `<android/native_window.h>` and probably all the `<android/*>` inclusions cannot be found. IDE (CLion) also marks them as missing because of it. Am I missing something in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Here is CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(App)

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

include(AndroidNdkGdb)
include(AndroidNdkModules)

android_ndk_gdb_enable()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/main/libs/armeabi-v7a)

set(LIBRARY_DEPS GLESv2 android log)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/lib/armeabi-v7a/freetype/include/freetype2)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS *.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HDRS *.h)

add_library(nativeegl SHARED ${SRCS} ${HDRS})
target_link_libraries(nativeegl log android)

android_ndk_gdb_debuggable(nativeegl)
```

and cmake launch params:

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=android.toolchain.cmake \
-DANDROID_NDK=/opt/android-ndk -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
-DANDROID_ABI="armeabi-v7a" -DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static \
-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-21
```

And this is the original Android.mk that works fine when I build in studio:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := nativeegl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%, %, $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp))

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c++11 -O2 -Wtype-limits -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wreturn-type -Wuninitialized

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue ndk_helper freetype

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
$(call import-module,freetype)
```

And Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-10
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem was in an error in one android-cmake file and wrong cmake variable in CMakeLists.txt. How did it happen? Probably I've followed some tutorial for older version of android-cmake. Here is how CMakeLists.txt looks now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(App)

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

include(AndroidNdkGdb)
include(AndroidNdkModules)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/main/libs/armeabi-v7a)

set(LIBRARY_DEPS GLESv2 android log EGL)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/lib/armeabi-v7a/freetype/include/freetype2)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS *.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HDRS *.h)

android_ndk_gdb_enable()

add_library(nativeegl SHARED ${SRCS} ${HDRS})
target_link_libraries(nativeegl log android)

android_ndk_gdb_debuggable(nativeegl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the include dir is not correct/present.

You can check the include dirs given to compiler with make VERBOSE=1

You can add it in your cmake with include_directories(...) 
Add the path where the android/log.h file is located.

Answer (score 0):

problem in file.
whenever u add .cpp file, u need to update in CMakeLists.txt like this

```
add_library(libraryName SHARED
file_name1.cpp
file_name2.cpp)
```

In my case.

```
add_library( native-lib SHARED
         native-lib.cpp
         webp_engine.cpp
         webp_link.cpp)
```

native-lib  --> library name(default name,i don't edit it).

webp_engine.cpp --> i created file.

webp_link.cpp  --> i craeted file